# Split hash request into separate strings rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I go about splitting this hash request into two different strings? 
I want to split it at `#<ActionDispatch`, which marks the beginning of the next image selected in the request.  How do I accomplish this in ruby?

**Request**

```
{"image"=>{"picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10c986d88 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bx/6z1z5yks56j40v15n43tjh1c0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130404-53101-3c2whv-0>,
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[picture][]\"; filename=\"background-pic.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @original_filename="background-pic.jpg">,
 #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x10c986d60 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/bx/6z1z5yks56j40v15n43tjh1c0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130404-53101-bvdysw-0>,
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[picture][]\"; filename=\"bible-banner.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @original_filename="bible-banner.png">],
 "album_id"=>"10"},
 "authenticity_token"=>"dr8GMCZOQo4dQKgkM4On2uMs8iORQ68vokjW0e4VvLY=",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "album_id"=>"10"}
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ImagesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json
    def index
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @images = @album.images.all
    end
    def new
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new
        #@image.picture.size.times {@image.build}
    end
    def create
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.new(params[:image])
        if @image.save
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def edit
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image"
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render "edit"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
        @image = @album.images.find(params[:id])
        @image.destroy
        @albumid = @album.id
        @id = @image.id
        FileUtils.remove_dir("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/image/picture/#{@albumid}/#{@id}", :force => true)
        redirect_to admin_album_images_path(@album)
    end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :picture, :image_id, :album_id, :albumcover, :image
  belongs_to :album
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :album
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

**Form View**

```
<%= form_for([:admin, :album, @image], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :album_id, :value => @album.id %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture, :multiple => true %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<%end%>
```

**Uploader Carrierwave**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.album_id}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: "picture" values is array of two ActionDispatch object. Why do you want split them?

Comment: how do I split that up then?  I want to split them up so I can send the image info to two different image objects.  It's for multiple image uploading.

Comment: They're already split

Comment: If so, then how do I select that second object?  It doesn't appear split up though.

Comment: Here is your pattern: b = {'a' => [1,2]} so to print '1' you have b.each {|k,v| p v[0]}

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an answer?  thanks

Comment: also you can write "x["picture"][1]" for getting second picture, or "x["picture"].each{|pic| p pic}" for printing each picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to split this hash request into its separate strings.

**Image Controller**

```
def new
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @image = @album.images.new
    end
    def create
        params[:image][:picture].each do |image|
            @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
            @params = {}
            @params['picture'] = image
            @image = @album.images.create(@params)
       end
        if @image.save
            if params[:image][:picture].size > 1
                flash[:notice] = "Successfully added images!"
            else
                flash[:notice] = "Successfully added image!"
            end
            redirect_to [:admin, @album, :images]
        else
            render "new"
            flash[:notice] = "Did not successfully add image :("
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

As a few commenters said above, what you have is a hash (key/value pair) with the key `picture` where the value is already an array, which by its nature is split up into discrete objects.

In order to access the array you need to ask for the `picture` key, then you can access each `UploadedFile` with [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) methods.

So starting with your initial hash:

```
hash_with_stuff = { "picture" => [#<UploadedFile1>,#<UploadedFile2>]}
  #=> { "picture" => [#<UploadedFile1>,#<UploadedFile2>]}
```

In order to get the array:

```
array_of_pictures = hash_with_stuff["picture"]
  #=> [#<UploadedFile1>,#<UploadedFile2>]
```

Now that you have the array, you can operate on it as you would any array:

```
# to get single elements out
array_of_pictures[0] # where the number is the index of the object in the array (starting with 0)
  #=> #<UploadedFile1>   #this is an UploadedFile object and will respond to its own methods

# to operate on each element with some method
array_of_pictures.each do |picture|
  picture.create_thumbnail
end
```

Does this make sense or were there other questions about working with this?

Comment: You explained this very well, thank you.  However, I am confused on how I reference the hash from the request.  I will post the rest of my code for reference.

Comment: What controller action is this from? Is it returned from one of the actions, or are you preparing it and sending it to a view?

Comment: I want it to separate it upon request so as to create two different image objects.  So I believe in the new/create actions.

Comment: Maybe a more directed question as well.  Do I need to specify what is inside the `"picture" => [specify this stuff]` or will rails automatically populate that information?

Comment: It looks like the hash is coming from a user entering information on a form and submitting it. The content inside of the `picture` value is already populated by the app.

Comment: At this point, it looks like you are trying to create `image` objects for each uploaded file, right? And it looks like you commented out an attempt to build an object for each item in the array. What do you need to do with each image? Do you need to save a record for each?

Comment: What are you using to upload files? paperclip? That could help me point you to a resource on managing uploaded files.

Comment: carrierwave ATM.  I can switch if that is a big issue though.  I've updated with the uploader info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27597/discussion-between-derek-duncan-and-jstim)

Comment: Just to clarify, and maybe someone can help more than I, but this question morphed from "hash access" to "creating multiple file entries with carrierwave". I answered the top stated question, but someone else may be able to better answer the carrierwave aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at this hash h={"strings"=>["stirng_object_1","string_object_2"]} which is almost similar to the hash that you posted except that the objects in the array are strings instead of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile Objects.

So from my example hash that I cited if I have to get first string object I would do

> h["string"][0]

Similarly if you would like to access the first ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile Objects you  can do ( assuming that your hash name is h )

> h["picture"][0]

Comment: how would I determine the hash name for that request?

Comment: Your hash name is params[:image] so if you wanted to loop over every picture, you'd do something like params[:image]["picture"].each